# android set ringtone to .ogg file

Tags: android, ogg, ringtone

I am trying to set the ringtone to `res/raw/sound.ogg` with the following code at the end of the function `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`:

```
Uri path =Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.sound);
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this.getApplicationContext(),
            RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, path);
```

I have also added the following to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

However, the ringtone is not changing. Any help?

Comment: Is Ringtone not changing or its not playing?

Comment: Have you checked if the path is returning the right value?

Comment: @Smit Not changing.  Yes the path is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since android 6.0 you need to check permissions at Run Time as well.

Here is the guidelines provided by Google : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Hope this will help. Let me know if you still have a problem.